# Xcode UI Testing with multiple predicates

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

Xcode 7 introduces new UI Testing tools. I want to filter an element that matching more than one query.

For instance. A table with cells that each cell has 4 labels inside them. 
I want to find element that contain.

```
label 1 text = "A"
label 1 text = "B"
label 1 text = "C"
label 1 text = "D"
```

Framework has api to give it one predicate. 
For example.

```
app.cells.containingPredicate
```

Anything available to filter using more than one predicate. Or any alternative to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain containingPredicate filters like below.

```
app.cells.containingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'A'")).containingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'B'")).containingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'C'")).containingPredicate(NSPredicate(format: "label BEGINSWITH 'D'"))
```

This will keep filtering out your cells until a cell with all for labels match.